# Why am I unable to destructure an optional parameter, even after providing a valid default?

Tags: typescript

Is this just a lack of feature or a bug in my code?

The goal is to make users able to call my functions without providing the options, and still destructure the options in the signature.

```
// Typings
export interface MyFunctionOptions {
  optParam?: boolean;
}
export type MyFunction = (mandatoryParam: string, 
                          opts?: MyFunctionOptions) => void;

// Functions
const myFunction: MyFunction = (mandatoryParam, { 
                                  optParam,
                                } = { optParam: false }) => {
  // use `optParam` directly, instead of `opts.optParam`
  return;
}
```

[Interactive REPL here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20interface%20MyFunctionOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20optParam%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20type%20MyFunction%20%3D%20(mandatoryParam%3A%20string%2C%20opts%3F%3A%20MyFunctionOptions)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myFunction%3A%20MyFunction%20%3D%20(mandatoryParam%2C%20%7B%20optParam%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20optParam%3A%20false%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) (be sure to enable `strictNullChecks` in the REPL

Comment: Your playground link seems to use a different syntax which appears to work: `const myFunction: MyFunction = (mandatoryParam, { optParam = false } = {}) => {
  console.log(optParam);
  return;
}` Why the difference ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I believe the first syntax is just TS sugar for the first expression, I just tried to use the ES6 syntax to see if it would fix. Also, please enable `strictNullChecks` in the options to see it fail, I'll update the answer to make this clearer. REPL link updated now.

Comment: I assume you also have `strictFunctionTypes` enable ? I have a solution, but it only works for `strictFunctionTypes: false`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I do, but I am curious, could you share the playground?

Comment: It's basically your solution but with the full type of the destructured parameter. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20MyFunctionOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20optParam%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20type%20MyFunction%20%3D%20(mandatoryParam%3A%20string%2C%20opts%3F%3A%20MyFunctionOptions)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myFunction%3A%20MyFunction%20%3D%20(mandatoryParam%2C%20%7B%20optParam%20%3D%20false%20%7D%3A%20MyFunctionOptions%20)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to specify  default values for destructured parameters is `{param = default}`:

```
function foo({param = true}) {
    console.log(param) // param is boolean
}

foo({}) // the parameter is required
foo({ param: true})
```

To make the parameter itself optional we can specify a default of `{}` for the parameter as a whole:

```
function foo({param = true} = {}) {
    console.log(param) // param is boolean
}

foo() // the parameter is optional
```

If we apply this logic to your sample we get :

```
const myFunction = (mandatoryParam: string, { optParam = false } = {}) => {
    optParam
    return;
}
myFunction("") // not required
myFunction("", {}) // optParam is optional
myFunction("", { optParam: true }) // optParam can be set
```

The problem appears when we try to specify the type of the function explicitly, then the second parameter is inferred to be `MyFunctionOptions | undefined` which is not indexable in any way. The simple solution to this unfortunate inference is to specify the type of the de-structured parameter explicitly:

```
const myFunction: MyFunction = (mandatoryParam: string, { optParam = false } : MyFunctionOptions = {}) => {
    optParam
    return;
}
myFunction("")
myFunction("", {})
myFunction("", { optParam: true })
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20MyFunctionOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20optParam%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20type%20MyFunction%20%3D%20(mandatoryParam%3A%20string%2C%20opts%3F%3A%20MyFunctionOptions)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myFunction%3A%20MyFunction%20%3D%20(mandatoryParam%3A%20string%2C%20%7B%20optParam%20%3D%20false%20%7D%20%3A%20MyFunctionOptions%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20optParam%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AmyFunction(%22%22)%0D%0AmyFunction(%22%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%0D%0AmyFunction(%22%22%2C%20%7B%20optParam%3A%20true%20%7D)%0D%0A)

Comment: "*the second parameter is inferred to be `MyFunctionOptions | undefined` which is not indexable in any way*" What do you mean is not indexable?

Comment: @doplumi For unions we can only access common properties, and `MyFunctionOptions` and `undefined` obviously have no common properties, so no properties can be accessed and de-structuring counts as property access